# how to change rails root PATH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I copied my rails project same directory using git.

```
/dev/rails_project/Original_project
/dev rails_project/Copy_project
```

and I type rails command on copy_project

```
ex) rails g nifty:scaffold test
```

but rails is scaffolding on original_project, and rails console also work on original_project

```
kai : Copy_project $ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.6)
2.1.2 :001 > Rails.root
=> #<Pathname:/dev/rails_project/Original_project>
```

I wanna change root PATH to copy_proejct..

Help.....

Comment: This should work in the Copy_project. Can you type pwd in your console to check you are in the Copy_project folder?

Comment: @Anand yes I checked current path :(

Comment: What do you mean you copied using git? Can you show the command you used?

Comment: @Anand command is only  git clone URL

Comment: Quit your console application and reopen and try again?